# facebook like button dynamic open graph meta tags

Tags: facebook, dynamic, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have this website with dynamic pages. Now there's a page with an overview of all articles and a page with detailed view that shows the complete article when you click it's title on the overview page. The URL of the detail page is something like this for example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/view.php?ID=43
```

Now i want to implement the facebook like button that only shows on the detailed page on the bottom of each article. I've found out that i have to use the Open Graph meta tags like below

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="My url" />
<meta property="og:image" content="my img" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My site name" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="admin number" />
```

Now my question is, how do i dynamically fill in the content values of each meta property? So that each article has it's 'own' like button. Is there a way to print php statements inside or something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can dynamically fill these values the same way you would dynamically fill any parameter or element in your HTML.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php print $title; ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />  
<meta property="og:url" content="myurl/<?php print $articleurl; ?>" />  
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php print $article_image; ?>" />  
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My site name" />  
<meta property="fb:admins" content="admin number" />
```

Don't forget to use http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to check your OGP tags are being interpreted as you desire. Facebook is very strict with it's expectations to follow protocol.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to place these metatags outside the head? Because the php query is obviously outside the document's head. And if i try to print these values before running the query, it won't work right.

Comment: 1) Run the database query once at the top of the page. Inside this, set some variables eg. $title, $articletext, $articleurl. 2) Output these variables in the head 3) Output these variables again in the body

Comment: It's not working, I've done it the way you said, but the like box is completely empty now, except for the base url of my website